# Replacing characters in Bash

Tags: bash, sed

I try to create a makefile using bash, and I use the following row

```
echo "OBJS = $(ls *.c | sed -r 's/.c\n/.o\s/g')" >> makefile
```

I want it to print the row:

```
OBJS = foo.o bar.o
```

for the files `foo.c` and `bar.c` in my working directory, but I get

```
OBJS = foo.c
bar.c
```

I'm not a `sed` expert so I guess I'm doing it wrong.. Can anyone give me a hand here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an array and parameter expansion:

```
files=(*.c)
echo OBJ = "${files[@]/%.c/.o}"
```